# Reload parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reload my child window's parent using jQuery?

Answer (score 106):

No jQuery is necessary in this situation.

```
window.opener.location.reload(false);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: Yep, just fixed that. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: It does take an argument - you can pass  in true to force reload (i.e. ignore cache)

Comment: The Mozilla reference site mentions this. I wonder if it is browser specific.

Comment: Even if the argument is non-standard, it will be ignored (http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#location-methods), so there's no harm in using it unless you want the default behaviour.

Comment: Not working in chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of null

Answer (score 25):

You can use [window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener), [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent), or [window.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top) to reference the window in question.  From there, you just call the `reload` method (e.g.: `window.parent.location.reload()`).

However, as a caveat, you might have problems with `window.opener` if you need to navigate away from the originally opened page since the reference will be lost.

Comment: +1 The marked answer used window.opener (which I understand why that is the preferred way), but I only had luck w/ window.top

Comment: If the child window was an iframe, you can use: window.parent.reload(); or window.parent.location.href='abc.html';

Comment: `reload()` is not a method of `window`.  You mean `window.parent.loacation.reload()`, which I have in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
parent.location.reload();
```

This should work.

Comment: And set the optional parameter to true to bypass the browser cache. e.g. parent.location.reload(true); ref. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Answer (score 6):

if you want to simply reload the parent window of child window:
This line code below is enough for that.

```
opener.location.reload();
```

if you want to reload parent window with query string (request) with old or new values. Following code will do the work.

```
if (opener.location.href.indexOf('?') > 0) {
      var baseUrl = opener.location.href.substring(0, opener.location.href.indexOf('?'));
      opener.location.href = baseUrl + "?param1=abc&param2=123";
}
else {
      opener.location.href = opener.location.href + "?param1=abc&param2=123";
}
```

this `opener.location.reload();` is not required in above example.

Answer (score 5):

This working for me:

```
  window.opener.location.reload()
  window.close();
```

In this case Current tab will close and parent tab will refresh.

Answer (score 3):

You can reload parent window location using :

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  top.frames.location.reload(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevents previous data from been resubmitted. Tested in Firefox and Safari.

```
top.frames.location.href = top.frames.location.href;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.opener.location.reload();
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for refresh parent window from child window

```
window.opener.location.reload(true);
```

for some version of IE this will not work so you can set some delay

```
window.setTimeout(window.opener.location.reload(true), 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
window.location.assign(window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Atlassian Connect Apps, use 
`AP.navigator.reload();`

See details [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/jsapi/navigator/)