# Refresh Page in iFrame after model pop up close

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe, modalpopupextender

I am opening page(Say page1.aspx) inside iframe using model popup extender. In that child page, again there is page(Say page2.aspx) opeing in iframe using model popup extender. Now on closing the page2.aspx, I want to refresh and reload page1.aspx. If I use

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshParent", "setTimeout('window.parent.refresh();', 500);", true);
```

then it shows error

```
"Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'refresh'"
```

How can I do so?

Comment: try window.parent.location.reload as in discussion [reload-parent-window-from-child-window][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window

Comment: It neither gives error nor works...

Comment: post your exact code please

Comment: @Ted.Sorry.. It worked now but it loads the parent page as it was before postback.

Comment: Yes. I want the parent page to be displayed based on the data entered in popup

Answer (score 0):

call this function javascript to reload parent page

```
function RefreshParent(sender, eventArgs)
  {
     document.location.reload();
  }
```