# Closing a browser tab/window reloads parent tab/window

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, share, facebook-social-plugins

In my application, I have added facebook share.

```
var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id='+data.clientId+'&link='+l+'&redirect_uri='+r+'&description='+description+'&display=popup';
window.open(url, 'fbshare', 'height=600,width=600,modal=yes,alwaysRaised=yes');
```

If I click cancel button, the window is supposed to be closed. Instead its redirecting to redirect_uri given in the query params.
I fixed this problem by closing the window manually through my application.

But the problem is after closing the facebook share window, its reloading the parent window.

Anyone knows how to stop the parent window from reloading?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window, it's relevant.

Comment: My problem is parent window reloading on close of child window. Then how it is relevant.