# javascript / reload() / Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to refresh parent browser at child browser.

`opener.location` is working but, `opener.locaiton.reload` not working.

Is there anyone who knows the reason??

Comment: What is the exact code?

Comment: I think this is same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this `window.opener.location.reload(false);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I tested it in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Safari on Windows 7.

```
<button onclick="window.opener.location.reload();">refresh</button>
```

Check this: [Refresh parent on close popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup).