# refresh different page from current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I have 2 separate pages, index and add_data. Initially, index page is open and this page has a link that opens add_data page in a different tab.  Now add_data page has a form whose data is getting saved through ajax.if the ajax returns a success message, I wish to refresh the index page.

code on index page responsible for redirection

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>class/add_data" target="_blank">Add Data</a>
```

Code of ajax on add_data page

```
jQuery.ajax(
          {
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "class/student/" ,
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(res) 
              {
                console.log(res);
              },
          });
```

Can anyone please tell how this can be done

Comment: How are these pages linked together? Does index contain add_data in a frame?

Comment: @Thomas Timbul these are 2 seperate pages

Comment: You can't refresh a page unless it is open. I'm not sure I really understand what your hoping to do.

Comment: @Thomas Timbul i have updated the post, hope it gives a better understanding

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window

Comment: @Thomas Timbul I have tried this link, but it didn't help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**index page**

```
<a class="click" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>class/add_data" target="_blank">Add Data</a>

<script>

 localStorage.setItem("return_suc", "0");
 $('body').on('click', '.click', function(){
    localStorage.setItem("return_suc", "1");
 });

window.setInterval(function(){
    if(localStorage["return_suc"] == "1"){
        location.reload();
    }
}, 500);

</script>
```

**add_data page**

```
jQuery.ajax(
      {
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "class/student/" ,
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(res) {
             localStorage.setItem("return_suc", "1");
          }
      });
```

Comment: Praneethi don't want to replace the page, just a refresh/reload

Comment: :D no no it doesn't replace the page, it'll redirect to you index file

Comment: i don't want to redirect, i wish to stay in same page and refresh another page

Comment: you want new tab or window  ?

Comment: i have updated my post, can you please give it a look again

Comment: @sammy check again

Answer (score 0):

As per [Reload parent window from child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window) you can use `window.parent.location.reload()`, assuming you have opened the `add_data` page using JavaScript `window.open(...)` from within the `index` page.