# Reload parent window

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a Tampermonkey script that opens another tab when a button is click, I then want it to reload the parent tab whilst focused on the new tab that was opened.

I have tried all the suggestions in this SO question but none of them work.
[Reload parent window from child window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318006/reload-parent-window-from-child-window)

Some of the suggestions give me the error
"failed! Permission denied to access property "reload" on cross-origin object"

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("loc1/?q") > -1) {
window.parent.location.reload(true);
} else if (window.location.href.indexOf("loc2/?q") > -1) {
var parameters = '\"' + mac + '\", \"' + ln + '\", \"' + num + '\"';
var btnEle = "<button id='add' type='button' onclick='passData(" + parameters + ");' class='btn btn-outline-success btn-sm'>Add</button>"
var btnAdd = $(this);
btnAdd.append(btnEle)
}

unsafeWindow.passData = function(mac, ln, num) {
(async function(){
    GM.setValue("mac", mac);

    var prev = mac;
    var search = prev.replace(/\:/g, '%3A');
    var searchUrl = 'https://url.com/loc1/?q=' + mac
    var loc1Tab = window.open(searchUrl, "_blank",);
    loc1Tab.focus();
})();
}
```

Comment: `window.parent` is not a parent tab, it's a parent page of a `<frame>` or `<iframe>`.

Comment: So is there any way to reference the parent tab?